# How can users I am not friends with like my picture

Tags: facebook

How can I set my Facebook settings so that people I am **not** friends with can like my pictures? Simply putting them on “public” did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To set Facebook privacy, click the privacy settings icon in the top bar, then "Who can see my stuff", and select "Friends" from the dropdown menu:

[image: Facebook privacy menu]

**Note that this will only apply to your posts from now on.**

To change privacy settings for an existing post (or image), go to your profile page, locate the image, click "Edit" and select a new privacy setting from the dropdown menu:

[image: Facebook image privacy]

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was asking.  I have noticed that for some people who I'm not friends with, I can like their photos, but for others I can't (even though I can view them in both cases).  I can't find any setting to control this though.

Comment: Yes, there *is* something to do with the privacy settings when you publish your posts. If you keep the privacy to only your friends, then other people won't be able to see it and would not be able to like your post.